# Always getting first value as false while searching a number?

Tags: c#, type-conversion

What I'm trying to do is to allow the user to search how many `false` or `true` values are saved in a `bool` Vektor It's also important that the program should handle input errors.

I guess I have to use `Convert.Boolean` but I don't know how. At the moment I'm keep getting the same thing whether I search numbers or letter.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Random newRandom = new Random();
    int slumpTal = newRandom.Next(1, 101);
    bool[] boolVektor = new bool[slumpTal];

    //var nacas = Convert.ToBoolean(Convert.ToInt32("0"));

    for (int i = 0; i < boolVektor.Length; i++)
    {
        int slump = newRandom.Next(0, 2);
        if (slump == 0)
            boolVektor[i] = true;
        else
            boolVektor[i] = false;
    }
    {
        Console.Write("Skriv in sökOrd: ");
        string searchWord = Console.ReadLine();
        bool search = false;

        for (int i = 0; i < boolVektor.Length; i++)
        {
            if (boolVektor[i] == search)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("The following were found: " + boolVektor[i]);
                search = true;
            }
            if (!search)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Your search failed");
            }
        }
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the expected output? The index of the true/false?

Comment: "What I'm trying to do is to allow the user to search how many false och trues saved in boolVektor" - that sounds like *counting*, but you don't have any counting in your code.

Comment: You dont do anything with `searchWord` . I guess you wanted to check `if(boolVektor[i] == searchWord)`

Comment: @TheSkimek I'm guessing that did not work because you can't compare bool to string so he put that there for some reason.

Comment: I guess `search` is supposed to simulate the user input of `FALSE`.

Comment: Yeah. I see. But I shouldn't have to use Contan or LINQ-methods in my searching. Don't even know whats LINQ-method for.

Comment: @EpicKip Yeah right i just realized. Still comparing to `search` is most likely wrong. He has to convert the User input correctly (or the bool value to a string) to compare the array.

Comment: Lets focus on one thing at a time... do you know how to convert from user input to boolean? Because that seems to be the first step from your current state towards a solution. (By *do you know* I mean, *if you don't know, start searching, because this was already answered before*)

Comment: Yeah, exactly But how I can convert the user input correctly? What am I suppose to do?

Comment: IF `search` is supposed to simulate the user input of `FALSE` then you should not change the value of `search`!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To search for a value of a certain data type in an array, you need to convert the user input into that datatype. Then you go ahead and compare the converted value in the same manner as you do it now.

The conversion can be done the following way:

```
Console.Write("Skriv in sökOrd: [TRUE|FALSE]");
string searchWord = Console.ReadLine();
bool search = Convert.ToBoolean(searchWord);

bool foundAnyMatches = false


for (int i = 0; i < boolVektor.Length; i++)
{
    if (boolVektor[i] == search)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("The following were found: " + boolVektor[i] + 
        "Index: " + i);
        foundAnyMatches = true;
    }
}
if (!foundAnyMatches)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Your search failed");
}
```

and please don't change the `search` value! because you use it as the search condition!

**EDIT:**

As for the handling of wrong input you can put the conversion into a [try/catch](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/try-catch) block or you can use the [Boolean.TryParse()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.boolean.tryparse(v=vs.110).aspx) method

Comment: Did not know Convert.ToBoolean worked on strings, never had to use it. Cool to know!

Comment: @EpicKip never used it before either ;) but it doesn't even care about case, you can write even `falSE` and it will convert correctly

Comment: Btw, maybe put the if(!search) outside of the for. I know OP did it like that but I'm guessing its a mistake :)

Comment: @EpicKip thanks, it was even wronger than I thought. I changed it

Comment: @Evens as for the handling of wrong input you can put the conversion into a try/catch block or you can use the [Boolean.TryParse](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.boolean.tryparse(v=vs.110).aspx) method

Comment: @MongZhu yeah, I see. But whenever I use try/catch block it couldn't compile. I don't know why. Maybe I'm missing something.

Comment: @Evens please edit your post and add the code with the try catch block. Then I can have a look on it

Answer (score 3):

**I made your current method working and explained some stuff in the comments:**

```
Random newRandom = new Random();
int slumpTal = newRandom.Next( 1, 101 );
bool[] boolVektor = new bool[ slumpTal ];

for ( int i = 0; i < boolVektor.Length; i++ )
{
    int slump = newRandom.Next( 0, 2 );
    if ( slump == 0 )
        boolVektor[ i ] = true;
    else
        boolVektor[ i ] = false;
}

Console.Write( "True/False: " );
bool search = Convert.ToBoolean(Console.ReadLine()); //Thanks Mong Zhu
bool foundMatches = false;

for ( int i = 0; i < boolVektor.Length; i++ )
{
    if ( boolVektor[ i ] == search )
    {
        //If you do boolVektor[i] it will just show true/false
        Console.WriteLine( $"The following index is found: {i} " );
        foundMatches = true;
    } 
}
if ( !foundMatches ) //We check if the search failed here because now the search is finished
{
    Console.WriteLine( "Your search failed" );
}
Console.ReadLine();
```

---

**If you want to count the number of occurrences of the user input then replace the `for` loop by this:**

```
int count = boolVektor.Where( row => row == search ).Count();
if(count != 0)
{
    Console.WriteLine( $"{count} items were found" );
}
else
{
    Console.WriteLine( "Your search failed" );
}
Console.ReadLine();
```

Comment: "if ( !search ) //We check if the search failed" unfortunately this checks only weather the user was searching for `FALSE`

Comment: Oh oops! I'm still using the search variable. Thanks for catching that!